# Not getting access related errors while updating records from LWC and with sharing apex

Tags: apex, dml-operations, with-sharing

I am trying to update records which I don't have update access on. I am expecting to get errors for such records but it updating successfully.

my org object owd is public read only and profile access is Read, create, edit, delete. and trying to update records using

**Database.SaveResult[] dmlResults = Database.update(recordsToUpdate,false);**
but all is success in dmlResults.

From record detail page, am getting error like 'You don’t have permission to take that action on this record or related records. For help, contact your Salesforce admin.'

Comment: are you executing it from developer console annonymous window?

Comment: Am calling @AuraEnabled method from LWC component. Which is placed on home page of user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected behaviour. LWC does not respect the CRUD access. You need to explicitly handle the CRUD access check before inserting the record in Salesforce via a lightning web component.

You can use [Write Simplified and Secure Apex with Spring ’23 Updates](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2023/05/write-simplified-and-secure-apex-with-spring-23-updates) to address the user crud access check.

Database operations can specify user or system mode using the keywords as user or as system.

```
Account acct = new Account();
acct.Name = 'Test';
try {
    insert as user acct;
} catch (SecurityException ex) {
    // handle exception
}
```

you can also read my blog:- [DO LWC RESPECT THE CRUD ACCESS IN APEX METHOD?](https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/09/05/creating-a-record-in-lightning-web-component-best-practise-part-1/)

Comment: After adding dmlResults = Database.update(recordsToUpdate,false,AccessLevel.USER_MODE); its worked

Thanks Sanket for your quick response.

Comment: @ParmanandShete, Great, You can accept the answer.